# How do I troubleshoot pre_get_posts with Debug Bar?

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I am using `pre_get_posts()` on a custom post type Archive page, to change the sort order. When I view the query using Debug Bar and WP Query Monitor, I can see that my action is indeed firing. If I `print_r` the `$query->query_vars` I can see the correct query. But, the post order on the front end doesn't change. I've checked and I'm not using conditionals that aren't set up yet (eg, I'm not using `is_post_type_archive()` but rather `$query->is_post_type_archive()`).

There is an awful lot of information presented in Debug Bar and WP Query Monitor - where do I dig in to find out why my posts are being ordered differently (by date) rather than by my specified orderby parameter?

For reference, I am on a sub-site of a WPMU network, using a child theme. My code (in my child theme functions.php) is:

```
function swm_custom_post_order_sort( $query ) {
    // don't do this on the admin end - we only want this on the front.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // is it the main query on the Film Archive page?
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'film' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'name' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
            $query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );
            // print_r( $query );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'swm_custom_post_order_sort' );
```

In fact, none of the `$query->set( something )` options work. If I use  `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 )`, I don't get 3 posts, either. Something, somewhere, is overriding this action, maybe?

The custom post type is registered through a plugin (Toolset Types). The settings for the custom post are in this screenshot: https://snipboard.io/hFMCKP.jpg
Which maps to the following:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function toolset_function() {
    $labels = array( ... lots of labels here );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'film',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => false,
        'feeds'                 => false,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Film', 'some-text-domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Documentary films, including short films.', 'some-text-domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'special-feature', 'availability' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-editor-video',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'film', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'toolset_function', 0 );
```

Comment: Does the post type have archive enabled, i.e. `has_archive` set to `true` (or a custom slug) when registering the post type? And I suppose that `suppress_filters` is disabled just for debugging?

Comment: Yes, `has_archive` is true. And `suppress_filters` was a failed Hail Mary that made no difference.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, enabled. Can you show your post registration code?

Comment: The post type is registered using the Toolset Types plugin, not my own custom code. But I could tell you what options are checked? (The options map to the options you would normally set during post registration, eg has_archive, show_in_rest, etc)

Comment: Maybe you can export just the *code*? If not, perhaps a screenshot of the settings would be helpful. And what's the URL of the archive page, is it like `example.com/site1/film` (if you're using subdirectory in MU)?

Comment: The URL is https://2020.encounters.co.za/film/ I will update the question with the screenshot you've asked for.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with my theme, Divi.

Comment: Yes, that's what I also thought of and your code seems just good, so try (temporarily) switching to a default theme and/or deactivate all plugins except Toolset.